# Low level windowing API for OS X

Tags: c, macos, sdl, glut, glfw

I am looking for a low level windowing API for OS X that creates (or allows me to easily create) an OpenGL context. I have tried GLUT, GLFW, SDL, and the Cocoa windowing system, but they all have some pretty serious problems.

- GLUT seems perfect for the task at first, but the inability to do my own run loop is not going to cut it for this app without forcing me to do a lot of extra work and it seems GLUT does not deal well with multithreading.
- GLFW is also excellent and flexible, but setting it up for use in the project seems impossible. I have followed a dozen tutorials and I still get linking errors on the build machine OR launch errors on other machines.
- SDL is... SDL. Getting things going is easy, but it quickly becomes an "SDL app". It is very difficult to get things done without SDL becoming the only useable framework for particular tasks.
- Cocoa is not a low level API. The overhead of creating a Cocoa window (and the Objective-C that comes with it) is far to high. My tests show that it takes four megabytes or so so get the same results as the one or two of the other methods.

Is there anything else out there that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the newer version of OpenGL ( 3.0 and on. ) If used together with SDL 1.3 you can create a cross-platform OpenGL context. You'll have your own loop and basically control everything yourself. And you will also be following the new standard for OpenGL, not the old, deprecated ( ? ) one.

You can check out [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial1%3a_Creating_a_Cross_Platform_OpenGL_3.2_Context_in_SDL_%28C_/_SDL%29) tutorial to get started.

SDL 1.3 can be quite annoying to set up and compile correctly, but once you are done with that, the rest is pretty straight forwards.

Comment: I'll try that this afternoon. Thanks.